# Massive ICMP ping fair use policy

Tags: ping, icmp

I made a (Java) tool capable of issuing tens of ICMP pings per second towards individual hosts. For example for 1000 different hosts it takes about one minute to send the pings and wait for and collect any responses from the individual hosts.

The purpose of this tool would be to monitor periodically the functioning of network connectivity for a collection of remote hosts.

Am I free to push this tool to its limits in setting any high value of pings per second and in the total amount of hosts? Or should I restrict this in order to avoid me to be banned or blocked by anyone? How costly or annoying are ICMP Pings on networks?

Comment: What's your motive? Are you probing particular people's networks? If so, what for? Are you surveying the Internet generally? The answers are very different depending on what you're probing and why you're probing it.

Comment: Added the purpose of the tool to the question.

Comment: So the large number of pings are to distinct, unrelated hosts? Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. However they may be contained in the same CIDR /18.

Answer (score 1):

Simple PING packet is 74 bytes long, including the Ethernet frame header and the IP + ICMP headers, plus the minimum 32 bytes of the ICMP payload - so it's not that big  even 1000 of them.

[image: ICMP PING packet]

But you should not use PING too much in my opinion. Network admins can detect such abnormal network behaviour and try to contact you or block your IP. Also IDS and routers can cut you off because of their policy.

The purpose of ICMP PING packets is to help network admins to diagnose network infrastructure problems. Typical use is to send a small number of packets to a target machine, like:

```
$ ping stackoverflow.com
Pinging stackoverflow.com [151.101.129.69] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 151.101.129.69: bytes=32 time=72ms TTL=57
Reply from 151.101.129.69: bytes=32 time=73ms TTL=57
Reply from 151.101.129.69: bytes=32 time=73ms TTL=57
Reply from 151.101.129.69: bytes=32 time=72ms TTL=57

Ping statistics for 151.101.129.69:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 72ms, Maximum = 73ms, Average = 72ms
```

As you can see the system ping command sends four packets - it's enough to diagnose the problem. Of course you can change the size of packets and their number.

In my opinion any other usage of ICMP PING (bigger number of packets, high speed of sending or a large size of packets) is a sign of abnormal usage. It is very often related to a virus/trojan/worm network infection, agressive port scanning by hackers or DDoS attack.

You want to send ~1000 packets - IMHO it's way to many. You should give a possibility to change this number.

Comment: Thanks for indicating the actual amounts of bytes, which indeed are quite small. I have still no idea however what means "too much" and what are the policies.